# Running batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have been working on a manager application for a Minecraft server, when I run my program, the console shows and disappears, if I run it manually, it runs without and problems. My code:

```
Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = textBox2.Text,
                    //Arguments = textBox3.Text,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                }
            };

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
server = process;
process.Start();
```

Batch file code (idk what language are batch files, so I used default one - Select Language):

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.3.jar -o false
```

BTW. Can you start processes without creating files ? (ex. Start process "java -jar example", without creating file) ?

**@Edit** Answer to the third question: [Answer to the third question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4aef1e9-3177-42e1-b49c-1629863fc5aa/c-running-batch-file?forum=csharpgeneral)

My full code (MessageBoxes are in Polish, becouse im from Poland, but later i will add support for other languages):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Process server;

        private Boolean runServer()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(textBox2.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Brak określonej ścieżki dostępu! (" + textBox2.Text + ")", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }

            Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = textBox2.Text,
                    //Arguments = textBox3.Text,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                }
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
            server = process;

            if (process.Start())
                return true;
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nie można włączyć serwera!", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private String ReadFile(String filename, int line)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
            }

            return reader.ReadLine();
        }

        private void ReloadOPs()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sciezka dostępu do pliku z listą graczy posiadających OP nie istnieje! (" + textBox1.Text + ")", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageOptions;
                textBox1.SelectAll();
                return;
            }

            String line = ReadFile(textBox1.Text, 0);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text).Length; i++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReadFile(textBox1.Text, i)))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    line = ReadFile(textBox1.Text, i);
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Lista graczy z OP, została odświeżona.");
        }

        // OPs combobox (OPs)
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            groupBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\ops.txt";
            ReloadOPs();
        }

        // Reload OPs button (OPs)
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReloadOPs();
        }


        // Save button (Options)
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void server_outputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            addConsoleMessage(e.Data.ToString(), true);
        }

        // Run server button (Menu)
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!runServer())
                return;

            server.BeginOutputReadLine();
            button6.Enabled = true;
        }

        // Stop server button (Menu)
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!server.HasExited)
                server.Kill();
            button6.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void addConsoleMessage(String message, Boolean refresh)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(message);
            if (refresh)
                listBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Works now, but after second message that batch file returned (?), program crashes becouse InvaildOperationException was unhandled.

Comment: Huh? Is the only problem that the console doesn't show anything? There's nothing here that would tell the console to wait for input or display anything. What do you mean by "run it manually"

Comment: have you tried debugging this code perhaps there is an exception happening and you are hitting the internal `Exit(0)` or something try debugging and reporting back

Comment: Nope, the console is just closing. run it manually - run manually bat file in which is the batch file code (start.bat).

Comment: I recommend you to subscribe the ErrorDataReceived event also

Comment: I will check it, wait a moment please.
@Edit Checked, it didnt display any message, just blank.

Comment: Can you try with adding the fullpaths to the java exe and jar file (so you get somethig like c:\program files\java\bin\java.exe etc) in yout batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Let's clarify some points. I assume you have a Batch file named `filename.bat` with this content:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.3.jar -o false
```

and with "run it manually" you mean you open a command-line window and enter: `filename`. Ok? However, you have NOT indicated how do you run your Batch file when NOT run it manually! If you double-click on it from the file browser, then your Batch file missing to change current directory to the one where the Batch file is:

```
cd "%~P0"
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.3.jar -o false
```

PS - Your Batch file should NOT be named `start.bat` because `start` is the name of an internal cmd.exe command!

Comment: Works now, but after second message that batch file returned (?), program crashes becouse InvaildOperationException was unhandled.